# If a user logs out of a Firebase Auth app will it log them out on all of their devices?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Say a user has 3 devices in which they are logged into a Firebase Auth app, using the same account. If they log out of one of those devices, will it log them out of the other two devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A signed in user is persistent on a device until they sign out on that device, or the user's auth token gets deleted somehow.